# Error de autoincrement en jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Este mensaje me da cuando realiza el **insert** en la base de datos y no da ningún error sólo da este mensaje de **advertencia**.

> Advertencia:   The class RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork is already flushing. The query will be executed without further changes being written to the database.  If the query is conditional upon changed data the changes may not be reflected in the results.  Users should issue a flush() call upon completion of the dependent changes and prior to this flush() to ensure correct results.

```
    NclDocumento documento = null;
    try {
        NclTipoDocumento tipo = findTipoDocumentoById(tipoD.getValue());
        if (numero != null && numero != 0 && anioSelected != null) {
            documento = findAcuerdoByNumeroAndAnioAndTipoDocumento(numero, anioSelected, tipo);

            if (documento != null) {
                return new Response<>(documento, ResponseStatus.OK_INSERT);
            }

        }

        if (documento == null) {
            documento = new NclDocumento();
            documento.setNumero(122);
            documento.setAnio(2014);
            documento.setFechaEmision(new Date());
            documento.setIdTipoDocumento(em.find(NclTipoDocumento.class,1));
           if (firma != null && firma.getEmpleado() != null) {
               documento.setIdFirma(firma.getEmpleado());
            }
            documento.setFechaCreacion(new Date());
            documento.setUsuarioCreacion(usuarioLogueado);
            documento.setActivo(true);
        }

        em.persist(documento);
        em.flush();
        return new Response<>(documento, ResponseStatus.OK_INSERT);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        String validationError = getConstraintViolationExceptionAsString(ex);
        log.error(validationError);
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        return new Response<>(ResponseStatus.ERROR_PARAMS, "Sucedio un error con la información: " + validationError);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        processException(ex);
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        return new Response<>(ResponseStatus.ERROR, "Sucedio un error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que está haciendo `em.flush();` es realizando lo que vendría a ser una "ejecución inmediata" del `em.persist(documento);`. El uso correcto del `flush()` es cuando quieres realizar la ejecución de las instrucciones sql que estan esperando al commit para ejecutar algunas otras que pueda que dependan de ellas, como por ejemplo traer el id autoincrementable del `em.persist(documento);` para realizar otras operaciones con el entityManager.

La advertencia te indica que estas forzando un `flush()` cuando ya se está realizando uno (como es normal al realizar un commit). Míralo como si estuvieras haciendo un doble commit al final y el implementador te está diciendo: "Estas mandando un commit que no está teniendo efecto por estar al lado de otro: ¿Estás seguro que no debería ir antes?"

No es un error, sino una advertencia de que algo se te está pasando. Tal vez le has puesto autocommit y el flush ya no debería ir.

Comment: Pues le hice el flush  para que exactamente hiciera el commit pero no guarda el registro en la base de datos